# Android handle screen orientation

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a different layout for landscape mode and placed my ***xml*** in a directory called ***layout-land***, so far so good. The problem is each time the screen is rotated onPause(), onStop() and onCreate() are called again, I don't want this. So instead I added:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

to my class in the manifest, but now I cannot use the xml in layout-land folder.
So how can I customize screen for portrait and landscape mode without calling onCreate() again?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more on your context

Comment: Do NOT use this hack.. Google around for why.  Rather than try to hack around Android's way of working, learn it and work with it.  It makes total sense and is an elegant solution to mobile app management.  Use the lifecycle and always assume that as soon as your activity is no longer in the foreground, it might be killed and the next callback will be onCreate().  Code accordingly and you will  have a much more robust app.  Do what you've suggested above, and I'll find half a dozen ways to crash your app that you haven't even thought about, and all because you didn't code onCreate correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly handle the configuration change yourself. Since you have added `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`, it means you tell android that you are going to handle configuration change yourself.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(config);

// Checks the orientation
if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    //Here set the layout for your landscape mode
} else if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
   //Here set the layout for your portrait mode
  }
}
```

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) link.  It will be helpful.